# Is it wrong to say "what an irony is"?

Tags: word-usage, countability

Some rude person said my English was bad, because I said "I know what an irony is" instead of "I know what irony is". Although the second sounds better, I don't think the first is incorrect grammatically. Is it?

Comment: Expect people to say that something about you is bad (English or whatever). That is alright. But if they are rude to you - walk away.

Comment: Prior to your remark, were you talking about irony, ironies in general, or a particular irony?

Answer (score 7):

Although irony is listed in dictionaries with a plural as well, we don't normally say "an irony".

**EXCEPT in certain cases such as**: an irony of fate. An irony of history, An irony of situation.

- It was **an irony of fate** that the ship went down.

In everyday conversation, such as the OP's, one would **most likely** say:

"I know what irony is". It's use there is as an abstract noun. However, it is listed in dictionaries as countable. In that utterance, irony is a concept.

> Be Careful of the Ironies in Your Life History is full of irony.
>   Consider some of theses famous statements.

[irony and ironies](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/artificial-maturity/201504/be-careful-the-ironies-in-your-life)

Answer (score 5):

Both are correct.

- "Irony" is the *concept* of irony.
- "An irony" is an *example* of irony - an *ironic* situation.

Likewise "tragedy" is a concept, whereas "*a* tragedy" would be a specific, tragic situation.

[This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an%20irony&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20irony%3B%2Cc0) shows that "an irony" is being used with increasing frequency.

[This link](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22an%20irony%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1992,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en) will show numerous references in literature to "an irony".

Comment: Is it ok to say "definition of an irony" instead of "definition of irony"?

Comment: in my (US English) dialect, "an irony" sounds awkward and non-idiomatic; "an ironic situation" would be preferred.

Comment: @Hearth I feel the same way as a native BrE speaker.

Comment: @Strawberry We don't have the wider context, so I'm having to answer at face value. I've established that "an irony" can be correct, and in my answer I explain what "an irony" is. If I can explain what an irony is, then the OP could rightly respond "I know what *an irony* is".

Comment: Your examples refer to use as a countable noun. The OPs phrase is attempting to use an article with the noun in its abstract uncountable sense, which is why it sounds as odd to native English ears, as "I know what a sugar is". Despite people here often asking for "2 sugars in their tea".

Comment: @james Without context, we don't know whether or not the OPs phrase *is* attempting to use the countable or uncountable form of the noun.  Plus, I know what a sugar is: it's a soluble carbohydride, such as a monosaccharide (glucose, fructose) or a disaccharide (sucrose, lactose).  That's quite the irony - do you know what an irony is?

Comment: @Hearth: "an irony" sounds awkward because you're not used to hearing it. "tragedy" vs "a tragedy" proves the point, and the same applies to "irony" vs "an irony". I agree it sounds unusual but it's a matter of not hearing it used as often.

Comment: @Flater Which is kind of the point I'm trying to make; it's such a rare construction that native speakers like myself think it sounds wrong. That doesn't mean it is wrong, just that it's not idiomatic in my particular dialect.